# How to access google shared drive data with php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

All of my files and folders are inside shared drive named as "Z". I'm using google drive api to list all files and folders of the shared drive but it's returning me empty array. Is there any permissions issue

```
$parentId = 'shareddriveid';
$queryString = "trashed = false and '$parentId' in parents";
$parameters = ['q' => $queryString,'pageSize' => 1000,0,'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, fileExtension, fullFileExtension, kind, mimeType, createdTime, modifiedTime, iconLink, webViewLink, webContentLink, parents)'];
$f =$this->drive->files->listFiles($parameters);
dd($f);
```

Comment: what happends if you just search for a drive called z? without the shareddriveid

Answer (score 3):

You can get the Shared Drive's files on PHP using the following code:

```
// Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
$optParams = array(
    'corpora' => 'drive',
    'driveId' => 'your-shared-drive-id',
    'includeItemsFromAllDrives' => true,
    'pageSize' => 10,
    'supportsAllDrives' => true,
    'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

// print results
foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file){
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $file->getName(), $file->getId());
}
```

As the [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22corpora%22%3A%22drive%22%2C%22driveId%22%3A%22your-shared-drive-id%22%2C%22includeItemsFromAllDrives%22%3Atrue%2C%22supportsAllDrives%22%3Atrue%7D) endpoint states, you also have to set the ***corpora***, ***includeItemsFromAllDrives*** and ***supportsAllDrives*** parameters.